# For Loop Assistance

Tags: java, for-loop

So my for loop causes a crash and I know exactly why, but I'm unsure of a way to rewrite this to get it to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm trying to get it to take out money from a compounding interest each day and total it up for the month (which is set for ever 30 days). The user inputs the number of days they are trying to calculate for. So what is causing the crash is if they put in anything other than something divisible by 30.

I'm having difficulty coming up with a way to rewrite this and could use any suggestions. I would like it to do something if they put in 65 it calculates 2 months worth and then display like insuficiant days for month 3. Any help is always greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numDays; i+=30){
    double cash=0;
    for (int n=1; n < 30; n++){
        int currentDay;
        currentDay= n+i;
        cash=cash+dailyMoney[currentDay];
    }
    month++;
    if(monthlyChecks == null)
        monthlyChecks = "\nCheck on month "+month+": $"+df.format(cash)+"\n";
    else 
        monthlyChecks = monthlyChecks+"\nCheck on month "+month+": $"+df.format(cash)+"\n";
}
```

numDays is the user inputted number of days....
monthlyChecks is a String....
dailyMoney[] is the array that holds the amount for each day.

Comment: Suggestion I: Do not use double for financial calculations http://epramono.blogspot.com/2005/01/double-vs-bigdecimal.html

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace.  And the statements that declare and initialize the `dailyMoney` array.

Comment: How about asking the user to input months instead of days?

Comment: @StephenC I can post the stacktrace if you want it still, but I have tracked it back directly to the for loop for that reason. If it's not 30, 60, 90... the for loop crashes the program. If it is one of those everything work perfectly calculation and display wise. dailyMoney is initialized out of the loop up where the button is pressed after it receives the numDays so dailyMoney = new double[numDays]; and other than the loop crash because of non 30's it works fine as well.

Comment: @sparc_spread Great suggestion and I would if the entire thing wasn't dependent on days. It also calculates weekly paychecks as well as no withdrawals being taken and the compounding is happening daily so it needs to be days. Thank you though.

Comment: @matiasf Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into modifying that for accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, sounds to me like what you are trying to do with your "insufficient days for month 3" is this: (Assuming numDays is an int)

```
numMonths = numDays / 30 //If numDays is an int, this will round down.
extraDays = numDays % 30

for (int i = 0; i < numMonths; i+=30){
   double cash=0;
   for (int n=1; n < 30; n++){
      int currentDay;
      currentDay= n+i;

      cash=cash+dailyMoney[currentDay];
   }
   month++;
   if(monthlyChecks == null)
      monthlyChecks = "\nCheck on month "+month+": $"+df.format(cash)+"\n";
   else 
      monthlyChecks = monthlyChecks+"\nCheck on month "+month+": $"+df.format(cash)+"\n";
   }
}

//Then at some point
Systme.out.println("Insuffiecent days for " + numMonth + 1 " months. " + 30 - extraDays " days short).")
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a shot when I get back

Comment: Thanks. I didn't quite use this code, but I did use a few parts you put in so thank you. Basically I used the extraDays to figure out if there were more than extra days off of 30. If there wasn't it ran the calc as was. If there was I built a different for loop that would run through the months that were full and at the end it made the last month display as insufficient. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Given that user is required to enter days, maybe something like

```
int numMonths = numDays / 30;
int remainder = numDays % 30;

System.out.println ("Calculating for " + numMonths + " months");

if ( remainder != 0 ) {
    numDays -= remainder;
    System.err.println ("Insufficient days for month " + (numMonths + 1));
}
```

This should all be placed before the rest of your code, including (and especially) before the `dailyMoney = new double[numDays]` part.